# Chrome Dev Tools error: musexotic

Tags: wordpress, developer-tools

So the site is ecozohm.com. On the homepage chrome dev tools is reporting the error:

```
GET http://dev.musexotic.com/eco/wp-content/themes/ecozohm/img/bg-  lines.jpg net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I can not figure out how to solve this. I have disabled all plugins.

Wordfence scans report site is clean

I used a search and replace tool and found like 5 instances of dev.musexotic that was there and i replaced that string with ecozohm.com, but error still remains. When you click the index.php link in chrome developer on the error, it appears to point to the JQuery UI script in the header that is a part of WordPress. The version is the latest 1.11

Im out of ideas. Any help appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reference to "dev.musexotic..." URL in your file

> /themes/ecozohm/css/menu.css

from line no.1

```
#header-menu {
background: url('http://dev.musexotic.com/eco/wp-content/themes/ecozohm/img/bg-lines.jpg') center bottom repeat-x;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 0 5px 0;
text-align: center;
width: 1000px;
```

}

Try removing it. There may be occurrences in theme files as well.
Try performing search in the theme files as well.

Let me know if you want me to look at the theme files.

Comment: Thanks. that was it. It appears to be left over from a past hack. Removing it removed the error. thanks a bunch!